# C# classes that implement the same properties

Tags: c#, oop

I have a couple classes that have the same properties.

For example

```
public class Decimalclass
{
   public string SqlColumnName {get;set;}
   public SqlDbType SqlColumnType {get;set;}
   public Decimalclass()
   {
      SqlColumnType = SqlDbType.Decimal;
   }
   //...
}

public class Textclass
{
  public string SqlColumnName {get;set;}
  public SqlDbType  SqlColumnType {get;set;}
  public Textclass()
   {
      SqlColumnType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
   }
   //...
}

public class Intclass
{
  public string SqlColumnName {get;set;}
  public SqlDbType  SqlColumnType {get;set;}
  public Intclass()
   {
      SqlColumnType = SqlDbType.Int;
   }
   //...
}
```

As you can see those classes share the same properties, I am trying to learn about interfaces and abstract classes.

- How would you organize those classes by making an interface that
  holds the things they share?
- Is an interface the best way?
- Can I add those classes to a list of the type of the interfaces
  so that I can access the properties without having to cast?
- Why an interface and why an abstract class, what advantages they have
  overeachother

Comment: I would indeed use an Interface. What happened when you tried?

Comment: @user2864740 its working fine, but i am confused about interfaces and abstract classes and when to use each

Comment: I would not use an interface. An interface is better suited when the classes have the same methods, with different implementations. Class inheritance is better suited for shared implementation.

Comment: I don't believe you can mock (Moq) an abstract class, though.

Comment: @Jason what if for examle the IntClass and the TextClass share the same implementation of a method?

Comment: @user1492051 That is when you use inheritance. An example for an interface would be something like Area() on a IShape. All shapes have an area, but the way to compute it can be completely different.

Comment: @user1492051: IMO, an interface is exactly what this is for. Different objects will have strategic implementation (not unlike the strategy pattern). Many will argue against the use of an `interface`. But I stress the need for both an abstract class and an interface. Abstract class for common (and overrideable, that is `virtual` or `abstract`) methods/properties; the interface for unit testing (with Moq) and more.

Comment: @IAbstract and your username says it all ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do :

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
  public string SqlColumnName {get;set;}
  public SqlDbType  SqlColumnType {get;set;}
}

public class Intclass : BaseClass
{
   public Intclass()
   {
      base.SqlColumnType = SqlDbType.Int;
   }
}
```

**Updated to better answer the OPs Q**

The Interface specifies a contract that must be followed on the object implementing the interface. Whilst the abstract base class provides a method to implement the interface automatically in all objects that inherit from it.

```
    interface IBase
    {
         string SqlColumnName { get; set; }
         SqlDbType SqlColumnType { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class BaseClass : IBase
    {
        public string SqlColumnName { get; set; }
        public SqlDbType SqlColumnType { get; set; }
    }

    public class Intclass : BaseClass
    {
        public Intclass()
        {
            base.SqlColumnType = SqlDbType.Int;
        }
    }
```

So in that example the interface IBase says that all implementer must contain these two properties to meet the contract. This is useful especially when following an Inversion of Control IoC or Dependency Injection pattern. This allows you to implement the interface on new objects and maintain compatibility anything that takes an IBase as an argument.
The abstract class implements the interface which is then inherited by any object that inherits from the base class. Basically by using the abstract base class you don't have to specifically implement each property in your child objects.

Comment: Seems like you have an extra space in the inherited class. Base Class should be BaseClass.

Comment: I would personally use both an interface and abstract base.

Comment: @IAbstract I understand your thinking but honestly I dont know if I think it warrants both based upon the limited information. Also - fixed my typo.

Comment: I think a `protected set;` for `SqlColumnType` might be warranted as well. I'm not expecting this to change at runtime, after all.

Comment: The scope of this question probably doesn't warrant an interface and an abstract class. Also +1 to @JeroenVannevel

Comment: @Wjdavis5 you second update is what i was looking for i just didnt know how to ask it, thanks :)

Comment: -1: there's no reason for this base class to be abstract the way you've implemented it. See the answer by @Marcin for an implementation where an abstract base class is actually useful.

Comment: @JohnSaunders The OP was not asking if he should, rather when he would and an explanation of what they were used for.

Comment: @Wjdavis5: ok, that's about the OP. What's _your_ reason for using the `abstract` keyword?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I guess I prefer to think of it as described here (link below) : 
Where an abstract class says that the object 'is something' and the interface describes 'can do something'


http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/02/12/learn-this-when-to-use-an-abstract-class-and-an-interface/

Comment: @JohnSaunders Of course I'm always open to a good ole'fashioned schooling from someone who knows better than I.

Answer (score 4):

I would make the `SqlColumnType` abstract and read-only to force implementing it in derived classes.

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public string SqlColumnName { get; set; }
    public abstract SqlDbType SqlColumnType { get; }
}

public class Intclass : BaseClass
{
    public override SqlDbType SqlColumnType
    {
        get { return SqlDbType.Int;  }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a benefit in this over a `protected set;` and setting it inside the constructor?

Comment: You don't have to set it in constructor. And you can't force the derived class to set the property value. You could easily make `UnknownClass : BaseClass` which does not set the property value. Actually the second argument is quite important, isn't it?

Comment: Gotcha, that's indeed a benefit. The second argument is indeed important, totally overlooked that for a moment. +1